# AntD Form Input Pattern Rules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

i am trying to add a regex patter for an form input field to "not" accept any special charcaters and space as well.Only numbers and strings.But the regex pattern is not working. what i did for testing is following:

```
<Form.Item name="name" label={"name"} 
rules={[{pattern: new RegExp(/^a-zA-Z0-9/i),message: "No Space or Special Characters Allowed"},
{required: true,message: "Account name is required.",},]}>
<Input />
</Form.Item>
```

Not working for me. Following cases i need to implement the pattern to accept valid strings

- No special characters
- No Spaces
- Only Numbers and Strings

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct pattern for escape all special character and allow only your wanted characters.

```
pattern: new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/)
```

Your new code should be like below:

```
<Form.Item name="name" label={"name"} 
rules={[{pattern: new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/),message: "No Space or Special Characters Allowed"},
{required: true,message: "Account name is required.",},]}>
<Input />
</Form.Item>
```